# What are the qualities a good English teacher?

Tags: british-english, pedagogy

It's my first time using this site. I have a question that's been on my mind for awhile.

**What do you think are some qualities of a good English teacher?**

Context:

Currently I'm still pursuing my education at university. Over a period of time, I realized that I quite enjoy the process of teaching. My original goal was to teach philosophy or something related to my degree (Business Analytics) but my country doesn't really have any avenues for me to teach these subjects. My English skills have been pretty alright and I've managed to score good grades for English papers before coming to university (I know that good grades don't mean that you will be a good teacher).

I'm actually staying in Singapore and English is actually a primary language for most of us. However our language capabilities are nowhere near countries such as the US or UK. Currently I'm in the process of getting into my country's teaching course so that I can be a licensed teacher and teach in a secondary school (students will be between 12-16 years old).

Although I'm sure that I will be happy if I choose this route as my career I'm afraid that I may be letting my students down by not being that good of an English teacher.

Any advice would be great!

PS: Sorry if this isn't the right page to ask this question. I'm not too sure where else I can find a community like this. Also I've actually asked this question in the English Language & Usage exchange but I've been told I might have better luck here instead!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because It is better suited to https://academia.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This may work better on our meta site.